# Drupal Feeds Spider Xpath URL Import not working

Tags: drupal, xpath, feed

I want to use Drupal Feeds Spider to import a list of urls (in my case a list of imdb movies).

for doing that I installed Drupal Feeds, and Feeds Spider Fetcher.

when I try to get list of url I am use Xpath to get the links, there is one problem

for example here my list http://www.imdb.com/search/title?title_type=feature to get urls,

the xpath for urls is used `.//*[@id='main']/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]/a/@href`

but the Final link Be like this `href="/title/tt0993846/` Feeds can't import.

I want links be like this `href="http://imdb.com/title/tt0993846/`

I tried this Xpath `concat('http://imdb.com/', .//*[@id='main']/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]/a/@href)`

But it didn't work , show error `Download of failed with code -1002.`

Answer (score 0):

XPath 2.0 solution:

```
//td[@class='title']/a/resolve-uri(@href)
```